# How can i match second-last char of a string with RegEx

Tags: javascript, string, regular-expressions, angular

Angular app!

I need to hide the 2 second-last char of a string and replace them with "XX".

what i got:

```
+391234567890
```

what i need

```
+39123456XX90
```

How can i match this with a RegEx?
I want to use this pattern in *replace()* method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would look something like this:

```
let result = source.replace(/^(.*?).{2}(.{2})$/,'$1XX$2');
```

Where:

- `()` is a "capture group"
- `^` matches beginning of the string
- `.*?` matches as few characters as necessary to fulfill pattern
- `.{2}` matches two characters
- `$` matches the end of the string

And in the replacement string:

- `$#` replaces the content of a capture group, numbered from 1 to #.